# Есть ли возможность воспроизвести видео Rutuba на Android?

Tags: java, android, видео

```
public class AnimeVideo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anime_video);
    ((VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView)).setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://rutube.ru/video/f66861fbf4fb6b7a4dcca6b6ac16ae7c/"));
    ((VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView)).start();
}
```

}

Я как понял такой вариант не сработает так как чтобы заработало нужно указывать полный путь до видео файла. Типо "http................mp4"

http://rutube.ru/video/f66861fbf4fb6b7a7c/

А если нет такой ссылки и в rubute не получается мне получить такую ссылку, то как быть тогда?

Comment: посмотрите пример реализации клиента для рутьюб, возможно не нужно городить свой велосипед
https://github.com/tumb1er/RutubeAppProject

Comment: @IvanSolntsev, Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче надо было закинуть файл в gradle, которых на этом не говорится.
Все спасибо всем за помощь. Оставлю тут ответ может пригодиться кому